# Which settings can make a website not working after launching an EC2 AMI in another instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

My aim is moving my websites hosted in a EC2 t2.small in a t2.large instance.

I created the snapshot, then the AMI.

I launched the AMI in the new instance but neither the websites (after changing the DNS A record)

nor the phpMyadmin installed in http://ipaddress/phpmyadmin folder are reachable.

Which could be the problems/misconfigurations?

Here the error_log

https://kopy.io/Gr8AW

and here the httpd.conf

https://kopy.io/I9Z2E

Comment: Can you post the config files and error logs?

Comment: When you say "not reachable", what error are you receiving? If it is timing-out, then check the IP address and the Security Group.

Comment: Error_log: https://kopy.io/Gr8AW

Comment: What error are you getting in your web browser when you try to navigate to a page? Note that if you changed a DNS A record and you’re trying to access it via that, you might need to wait for the change to propagate before it will work (anywhere from hours to days, usually not more than 2 days). In the meantime, try accessing it via the IP directly to eliminate that variable. Also, make sure both ports 80 and 443 are enabled for all traffic in your instance security group.

Comment: Actually I'm getting DNS propagation in minutes, but even ip_address/phpmyadmin gives me a timeout :(

Comment: httpd.conf https://kopy.io/I9Z2E

Comment: @brads3290 You were right, the problem was the security group, only port 22 was open for the new instance...thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

To change instance types, all you need to do is:

- **Stop** the EC2 instance
- Change the **Instance Type**
- **Start** the EC2 instance
- Done!

Please note that if you have a DNS Name associated with the instance, then you should use an **Elastic IP address** on the EC2 instance so that it does not change IP address when the instance is stopped and started.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a snapshot and booted up then there are likely chances that some services might have stopped. Check if your PHP and other required services are running.
Also, if you have elastic IP, allocate to newly turned on server.

Comment: I allocate another ip and changed the A Record